# How to access a dynamic variable of a Python script from another Python script?

Tags: python, import, python-import

So there's two scripts: `script1.py` and `script2.py`. `script1.py` has a variable `x` that stores the string read from a file during runtime. In `script2.py`, I import `script1.py` and then run `script1.py` using the following: `script1.main()`. I then run a particular function in `script1.py` that is responsible for reading the file in question.

You might wonder why I don't just run that particular function in the first place instead of running the whole script. That's because `script1.py` does a bunch of other things that `script2.py` needs every time it is run.

I want to able to read what is stored in `x` when `script1.py` is run from `script2.py`. What I'm currently doing is essentially running part of `script1.py` twice. I want to know if it's possible to access the variable `x` without doing the following:

```
#script1

def read_file():
    f = open('file_path.txt')
    string = f.read()
    return string

def main():
    x = read_file()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And `script2.py`:

```
#script2

import script1
from script1 import *

def main():
    script1.main()
    x = read_file()
    print(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So essentially I want to know how this sort of thing is supposed to be done usually. Is it possible to get the value of `x` without having to run `read_file()` a second time? When `script1.main()` is executed, where is the value of `x` stored and how can I access it? Not sure if I should be using `import script1` or if I should use `from script1 import *` to achieve this.

Comment: make `script1.main` return `x`?

Comment: I would prefer an alternative, if there is one. What if I want to access multiple objects? Is that possible?

Comment: well yes you can return multiple objects...

Comment: You mean as an iterable?

Comment: yes as usual: `return x,y,z` which is a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `x` is a local variable in the `script1.main` function, it is not accessible from outside (neither from script2 nor even from script1). In fact, the object will be discarded after `script1.main` is finished.
If you want to reuse it, you need to store it somewhere else.

A quick fix is to make the variable `x` global. Then script2 can use it as `script1.x`.

```py
# script1.py
def read_file():
    return "foo bar"

def main():
    global x
    x = read_file()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# script2
import script1

def main():
    script1.main()
    #x = read_file()
    print(script1.x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you do not want to use the `global` syntax, an alternative is to define a mutable variable in the `script1.py` and let it store the variable you want to reuse. One possibility is to use `class`. Here, I am using `class` as a mutable storage. If you do not like it, other mutable objects such as `dict` would also work.

```py
# script1.py
class data:
    x = None

def read_file():
    return "foo bar"

def main():
    data.x = read_file()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# script2
import script1

def main():
    script1.main()
    #x = read_file()
    print(script1.data.x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```